# Cannot deploy CXF rest service in karaf 2.3.2 using ehcache

Tags: cxf, ehcache, apache-karaf

I have the following issue: trying to deploy a rest service as a bundle in karaf 2.3.2, using cxf, the following exception occured:

```
   Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-8" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/constructs/web/AlreadyCommittedException
   ...
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.AlreadyCommittedException not found by org.apache.servicemix.bundles.ehcache [149]
```

I tracked down the issue to a bad manifest in the ehcache bundle imported by cxf

```
    Installing bundle mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.ehcache/2.5.1_1
```

see the following bug report on service mix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SMX4-1303

My issue now: I know this is fixed in ehcache 2.6.XX , how can I fix this, knowing that cxf 2.7.5 and 2.7.6 (the latest) both import the bugged bundle ? 
I managed to fixed that once, but I can't remember what I did :/
Here is the feature I install:

```
     <feature name="wsserv" version="${project.version}" description="wsserv">
       <configfile finalname="/etc/wsserv.cfg">mvn:com.mycorp.karaf.datasources/wsserv/${project.version}/cfg</configfile>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.14</bundle>
        <feature version="3.2.3.RELEASE">spring-jdbc</feature>
        <feature version="3.2.3.RELEASE">spring-web</feature>
        <feature version="2.7.5">cxf</feature>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-web/2.0.3</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.mycorp.karaf.datasources/wsserv/${project.version}</bundle>
         <bundle>mvn:com.mycorp.karaf.webservices/wsserv.common/${project.version}</bundle>
         <bundle>mvn:com.mycorp.karaf.webservices/wsserv.dao/${project.version}</bundle>
         <bundle>mvn:com.mycorp.karaf.webservices/wsserv.business/${project.version}</bundle>
         <bundle>mvn:com.mycorp.karaf.webservices/wsserv.api/${project.version}</bundle>
  </feature>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error you have got is a typical classloading clinch. Without going into detail - wourkaround will be to make ehcache-web a fragment bundle of servicemix-ehcache.

Comment: sorry about the late reply. I don't quite get the "fragment bundle" thing. By the way, I found that ehcache 2.7.5 deploy properly in karaf, worth checking

Comment: Fragment bundle might be used to patch broken module. The thing is it allows you to override or extend bundle classpath (but not imports). The difference is that fragment must specify Fragment-Host header. Anyway, glad that you have got new version of ehcache deployed.